# Cannot insert int into mySql data with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to insert an int into the database using PDO, but for some reason it keeps failing with the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 ' in C:\vhosts\jpl\admin\add_project.php:119 Stack trace: #0 C:\vhosts\jpl\admin\add_project.php(119): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\vhosts\jpl\admin.php(25): include('C:\vhosts\jpl\a...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\vhosts\jpl\admin\add_project.php on line 119
```

Here's the code:

```
        $projectAdd = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO projects (title, short_description, long_description, image_location, display)VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', ?, :integer)");
        $projectAdd->bindParam(1, $test);
        $projectAdd->bindParam(':integer', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $test = "testbind";
        $value = 1;
        $projectAdd->execute();
```

Even if I use a direct int it still fails. I.E 0 instead of binding.

*Edit made an error on the question.

Comment: Why are trying to bind param 1 twice?

Comment: can you post the query? What happens if you try to execute it directly on the client?

Comment: Try changing `$projectAdd->bindParam(1, $testint);` to `$projectAdd->bindParam(2, $testint);`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$projectAdd = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO projects (title, short_description, long_description, image_location, display)VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test', ?, ?)");
//The variables need to be defined before binding.
$test = "testbind"; 
$testint = 1;
$projectAdd->bindParam(1, $test);
$projectAdd->bindParam(2, $testint); //change '1' to '2'
```